# Debugview doesnt work on windows 7 64

Tags: logging, windows-7, 64-bit, debugview

I'm writing an application and debugging it VS2010. It uses *"Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Logger.Write"* for logging. 
My machine runs Windows7x64 and am using VS2010 professional.

I can see the logs fine in windows event logger but I'd like to see them logs in DebugView.
Problem is, it doesn't seem to work... I can see other logs there bu not mine.

Searching the web, I found hints there is a problem with Windows7x64 or maybe with Visual studio 'hogging' the trace service.

I tried running DebugView in administrator mode - didn't help.

What am I missing? What else can I try?

Thanks,
Shay

Comment: DebugView can only see output that's generated by OutputDebugString().  It is an API function intended for debuggers.  I don't know the class you are using but it doesn't sound much like a debugger.  Use the .NET Trace class instead.